# Should I use scoped applications in ServiceNow or just develop in the global scope

Tags: servicenow

I have gotten mixed answers when asking other developers about the tradeoffs between scoped and global applications.

Our use case is that none of the applications will be sold, they are only used internally. Every time I use a scoped application, I inevitably hit a wall, needing to create a script include in the global scope to get something done. The scoped APIs seem very restrictive in some cases.

However, when creating a new application in global scope (in studio), it is labeled as "Legacy" which is a little scary. Will they eventually remove the ability to develop in the global scope altogether?

Answer (score 1):

if it is an application from scratch for a non existing functionality, then scoped app is the right approach because of all advantages it brings (runtime isolation, delegated development, studio, etc..) 
unless you want to extend an existing app, then pros/cons should be assessed.